# Symfony2: Collection validation causes entity field error

Tags: validation, symfony

In a form with a collection field, where the collection contains an entity field (eid in Member Type), adding validation of the collection causes the entity field throw the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Object of class Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Ethnicity could not
>   be converted to int

Without validation, the entity field is handled properly.  And adding the entity field to the validator has no effect.

The collection:

```
->add('members', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new MemberType(),
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'prototype' => true,
))
```

Member Type:

```
->add('include', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('Yes' => 'Yes', 'No' => 'No'),
    'empty_value' => false,
    'required' => false))
->add('fname', null, array('required' => false))
->add('sname', null, array('required' => false))
->add('dob', 'dob_age')
->add('gender', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'),
    'empty_value' => false,
    'required' => false))
->add('eid', 'entity', array(
    'property' => 'abbr',
    'label' => '',
    'class' => 'ManaClientBundle:Ethnicity',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                ->orderBy('e.abbr', 'ASC');
    }
));
```

Validation:

```
/**
* @Assert\Collection(
 *  fields = {
 *      "fname" = @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Member first name may not be blank"),
 *      "dob" = @Assert\NotBlank(message = "Member DOB may not be blank"),
 *      },
 *      allowExtraFields = true
 * )
 */
```

Member entity:

```
class Member 
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client",inversedBy="members",cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * 
     */
     protected $client;

    public function setClient(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

   /**
     * @var string $fname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fname", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $fname;

    /**
     * @var string $sname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sname", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $sname;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $dob
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dob", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dob;

    /**
     * @var string $include
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="include", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $include;

    /**
     * @var string $gender
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $excludeDate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="exclude_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $excludeDate;

    /**
     * @var integer $eid
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="eid", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $eid;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fname
     *
     * @param string $fname
     * @return member
     */
    public function setFname($fname) {
        $this->fname = $fname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFname() {
        return $this->fname;
    }

    /**
     * Set sname
     *
     * @param string $sname
     * @return member
     */
    public function setSname($sname) {
        $this->sname = $sname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSname() {
        return $this->sname;
    }

    /**
     * Set dob
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dob
     * @return member
     */
    public function setDob($dob) {
        $this->dob = $dob;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dob
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDob() {
        return $this->dob;
    }

    /**
     * Set include
     *
     * @param string $include
     * @return member
     */
    public function setInclude($include) {
        $this->include = $include;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get include
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getInclude() {
        return $this->include;
    }

    /**
     * Set gender
     *
     * @param string $gender
     * @return member
     */
    public function setGender($gender) {
        $this->gender = $gender;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get gender
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getGender() {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * Set excludeDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $excludeDate
     * @return member
     */
    public function setExcludeDate($excludeDate) {
        $this->excludeDate = $excludeDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get excludeDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getExcludeDate() {
        return $this->excludeDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set eid
     *
     * @param integer $eid
     * @return member
     */
    public function setEid($eid) {
        $this->eid = $eid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEid() {
        return $this->eid;
    }
```

Ethnicity entity:

```
class Ethnicity
{
    public function __toString() {
        return strval($this->id);
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->clients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string $abbr
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="abbr", type="string", length=5, nullable=true)
     */
    private $abbr;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Ethnicity
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set abbr
     *
     * @param string $abbr
     * @return Ethnicity
     */
    public function setAbbr($abbr)
    {
        $this->abbr = $abbr;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get abbr
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAbbr()
    {
        return $this->abbr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my error was the assumption that a collection field required a collection validator.  Instead, the validators simply needed to be on the entity that comprised the collection.  In this case, all I really needed to do was specify the validation in the Member entity (and remove the annotation assertion in the client entity.)  When I simplified the ethnicity entity field was properly handled.  So my error also included the notion that Symfony was more complex - not always the case, just sometimes true!

Answer (score 0):

Does your Member entity have a relationship to your Ethnicity entity? Judging from the name "eid" it looks like you are trying to force an Ethnicity class into an integer field ("eid").

It is really hard to find anything without seeing both entities.

Comment: Entities are added above.  Not sure of the value of adding a relationship.  It isn't necessary when there's no validation.  Ethnicity is just a lookup table for full  names and abbreviations for tracked ethnic backgrounds.

Comment: I wouldn't know how Doctrine is able to see the relation otherwise, since you are adding the collection into the member entity basically.
The only thing you could do is to add 
`"property_path" => false`
to the entity field, but you would need to process the data manually.